# Are variables set in include global in scope? If yes, any way to create a local variable?

Tags: jekyll, liquid

Are variables set in Jekyll `{% include %}` files global in scope? That is, do they leak into the page that included then and subsequent includes?

For example, I have an include file with the following contents:

```
{% assign ai__attributes = "" %}

{% if include.width %}
{% capture ai__attributes %}{{ ai__attributes }}width="{{include.width}}" {% endcapture %}
{% endif %}

{% if ai__attributes != "" %}
{% capture ai__ial %}{:{{ai__attributes}}}{% endcapture %}
{% endif %}

![{{include.alt | default image }}]({{assetpath}}/{{include.path}}){{ai__ial}}
```

This sets teh `ai__ial` variable if `include.width` has been set. If I call this once with `width` set, and then again with it inset, will the `ai__ial` from the first call leak into the second? Is there any way to avoid this, e.g., by scoping the variable?

Answer (score 2):

No way to set a local variable, but you can reset `ai__ial` in your include.

```
{% assign ai__attributes = "" %}
{% assign ai__ial = "" %}
...
```